# SQLITE Conditional Order By with CASE

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I want to order an SQLITE Query in different orders depending on the boolean `paid`.

The query works without the case statement.

The `due` column is of type `long` representing a date in unix time.

Withe the following query, I'm getting the following error:

> extraneous input 'ELSE' expecting {, ';', K_ALTER, K_ANALYZE, K_ATTACH, K_BEGIN, K_COMMIT, K_CREATE, K_DELETE, K_DETACH, K_DROP, K_END, K_EXPLAIN, K_INSERT, K_PRAGMA, K_REINDEX, K_RELEASE, K_REPLACE, K_ROLLBACK, K_SAVEPOINT, K_SELECT, K_UPDATE, K_VACUUM, K_VALUES, K_WITH, UNEXPECTED_CHAR}

```
SELECT transactions.* FROM transactions
    ORDER BY
    paid ASC,
    CASE paid WHEN 0
        THEN due DESC
        ELSE due ASC
    END,
    date DESC, title ASC
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM transactions
ORDER BY
    paid,
    CASE paid WHEN true THEN -1.0*due ELSE due END,
    date DESC,
    title;
```

This answer assumes that `due` is some sort of long timestamp, and then the second level of sorting in your expected `ORDER BY` clause should place more recent records first, when `paid` is true, and the reverse when `paid` is not true.

Comment: Thanks, I've clearified that due is a long representing an unix date. So I assume I can omit the `strftime`, since my due is actually a long?

Comment: @the_dani Yes, that makes it a lot simpler, q.v. the updated answer above.